# Kivy App immediately crashes on android, stuck in loop

Tags: android, python, kivy

The app works perfectly well in windows but on android it will not load on my phone.

I am using a samsung galaxy s3 running android 4.3

I have the phone in developer mode.

I am using the buildozer VM for virtualbox.

Heres the buildozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = EvenProblems

# (str) Package name
package.name = evenprobs

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3crystax,kivy
android.ndk_path = /home/kivy/Desktop/crystax-ndk-10.3.2/

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

The app will start and it will have a kivy logo and loading screen and then crash immediately. These are the logs. I have set the log_level = 2. I am hoping that someone can provide some answers on hope to stop the app from crashing when it starts. If anyone needs the apps code I can send you it. It consists of a few screens and boxlayouts. It works as expected in windows.

Im trying to boot it using:

```
 buildozer android debug deploy run logcat
```

Logs:

```
kivy@kivyvm:~/EvenProblems$ buildozer android debug deploy run logcat
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.10 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'pip install -q --user "appdirs" "colorama>=0.3.3" "sh>=1.10,<1.12.5" "jinja2" "six"'
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/kivy/Desktop/crystax-ndk-10.3.2
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=evenprobs --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3crystax,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/EvenProblems/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
# Cwd /home/kivy/EvenProblems/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[WARNING]: NDK version was set as r9c, but checking the NDK dir claims it is 10.3.2.
[WARNING]: The build will try to continue, but it may fail and you should check that your setting is correct.
[WARNING]: If the NDK dir result is correct, you don't need to manually set the NDK ver.
[INFO]:    Using Crystax NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9', '5', 'clang3.6', 'clang3.7']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 5
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     evenprobs: includes recipes (hostpython3crystax, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python3crystax, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    evenprobs has compatible recipes, using this one
# Build the application #17
# Copy application source from /home/kivy/EvenProblems
# Create directory /home/kivy/EvenProblems/.buildozer/android/app
# Copy /home/kivy/EvenProblems/main.py
# Package the application
# project.properties updated
# Gradle project detected, copy files /home/kivy/EvenProblems/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/evenprobs/src/main/java
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name evenprobs --name EvenProblems --version 0.1 --package org.test.evenprobs --android_api 19 --minsdk 9 --private /home/kivy/EvenProblems/.buildozer/android/app --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/EvenProblems/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
# Cwd /home/kivy/EvenProblems/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Getting Android API version from user argument
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[WARNING]: NDK version was set as r9c, but checking the NDK dir claims it is 10.3.2.
[WARNING]: The build will try to continue, but it may fail and you should check that your setting is correct.
[WARNING]: If the NDK dir result is correct, you don't need to manually set the NDK ver.
[INFO]:    Using Crystax NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9', '5', 'clang3.6', 'clang3.7']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 5
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     evenprobs: includes recipes (hostpython3crystax, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python3crystax, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    evenprobs has compatible recipes, using this one
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     evenprobs: includes recipes (hostpython3crystax, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python3crystax, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    evenprobs has compatible recipes, using this one
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/kivy/EvenProblems/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/evenprobs
[INFO]:    Selecting java build tool:
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 28.0.1
[INFO]:        Building with gradle, as gradle executable is present
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:    > Configuring > 0/1 projects > root project > Resolving dependenIncremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
[DEBUG]:    :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :checkDebugManifest
[DEBUG]:    :prepareDebugDependencies
[DEBUG]:    :compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :mergeDebugResources
[DEBUG]:    :processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :processDebugResources
[DEBUG]:    :generateDebugSources
[DEBUG]:    :incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :javaPreCompileDebug
[DEBUG]:    :compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :mergeDebugAssets
[DEBUG]:    :transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[DEBUG]:    :validateSigningDebug
[DEBUG]:    :packageDebug
[DEBUG]:    :assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Total time: 5.24 secs
[DEBUG]:    
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/kivy/EvenProblems/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    # Copying APK to current directory
[INFO]:    # APK filename not found in build output, trying to guess
[INFO]:    # Found APK file: /home/kivy/EvenProblems/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/evenprobs/build/outputs/apk/evenprobs-debug.apk
[INFO]:    # Add version number to APK
[INFO]:    # APK renamed to evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[DEBUG]:   -> running cp /home/kivy/EvenProblems/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/evenprobs/build/outputs/apk/evenprobs-debug.apk evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
Could not find hostpython, will not compile to .pyo (this is normal with python3)
No compiled python is present to zip, skipping.
this should only be the case if you are using the CrystaX python
# Android packaging done!
# APK evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk available in the bin directory
# Run '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/platform-tools/adb devices'
# Cwd None
List of devices attached
6e06d061    device

# Deploy on 6e06d061
# Run '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/platform-tools/adb install -r "/home/kivy/EvenProblems/bin/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk"'
# Cwd /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform
[  0%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  1%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  1%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  2%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  3%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  3%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  4%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  5%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  5%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  6%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  7%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  7%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  8%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  9%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[  9%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 10%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 11%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 11%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 12%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 13%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 13%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 14%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 15%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 15%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 16%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 17%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 17%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 18%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 19%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 19%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 20%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 21%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 21%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 22%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 23%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 23%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 24%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 25%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 25%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 26%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 27%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 27%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 28%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 29%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 29%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 30%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 31%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 31%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 32%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 33%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 33%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 34%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
[ 35%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 35%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 36%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 37%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
....
    [ 60%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 61%] /data/loc

al/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 61%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 62%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 63%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 63%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 64%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 65%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 65%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 66%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 66%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 67%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 68%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 68%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 69%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 70%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 70%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 71%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 72%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 72%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 73%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 74%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 74%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 75%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 76%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 76%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 77%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 78%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 78%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 79%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 80%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 80%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 81%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 82%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 82%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 83%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 84%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 84%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 85%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 86%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 86%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 87%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 88%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 88%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 89%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 90%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 90%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 91%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 92%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 92%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 93%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 94%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 94%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 95%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 96%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 96%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 97%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 98%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 98%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [ 99%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    [100%] /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
    /home/kivy/EvenProblems/bin/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk: 1 file pushed. 0.7 MB/s (9879478 bytes in 13.266s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/evenprobs-0.1-debug.apk
```

Then it gets stuck into a loop like this:

```
E/SMD     (  166): DCD OFF
I/System.out( 1348): 29 bLAR false
I/System.out( 1348):  ----Tether Manager - isWifiConnected------- true
I/SecureStorage( 3239): [INFO]: Secure Storage Daemon is preparing to run
I/SecureStorage( 3239): [INFO]: Secure Storage Daemon successfully binded a socket
D/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3239): QSEECom_start_app sb_length = 0x19a040
D/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3239): App is not loaded in QSEE
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3239): Error::Cannot open the file /firmware/image//sec_stor.mdt
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3239): Error::Loading image failed with ret = -1
D/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3239): QSEECom_start_app sb_length = 0x19a040
D/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3239): App is not loaded in QSEE
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3239): Error::Cannot open the file /firmware/image//sec_storage.mdt
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3239): Error::Loading image failed with ret = -1
E/SecureStorage( 3239): [ERROR]:Loading app sec_stor and sec_storage failed
E/SecureStorage( 3239): [ERROR]:Fail to open session with qualcomm
E/SecureStorage( 3239): [ERROR]:Error cannot connect to TA/driver!
E/SMD     (  166): DCD OFF
D/BatteryService(  348): update start
D/BatteryService(  348): level:46, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 3975, temperature: 318, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303560, invalid charger:0, online:4, charge type:0, current avg:0
D/BatteryService(  348): Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
D/BatteryService(  348): stay LED for charging
D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(  893): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(  893): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar(  893):  mBrightnessEnablebySettings = true mBrightnessEnablebyBattery = true mBrightnessEnablebyDisableFlag = true
D/LockPatternUtils(  348): isPcwEnable = null
D/CMASMessage(  348): [update] mShowingCMASText is false
D/CMASMessage(  348): CMASIcon was GONE :
E/SMD     (  166): DCD OFF
I/SecureStorage( 3241): [INFO]: Secure Storage Daemon is preparing to run
I/SecureStorage( 3241): [INFO]: Secure Storage Daemon successfully binded a socket
D/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): QSEECom_start_app sb_length = 0x19a040
D/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): App is not loaded in QSEE
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): Error::Cannot open the file /firmware/image//sec_stor.mdt
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): Error::Loading image failed with ret = -1
D/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): QSEECom_start_app sb_length = 0x19a040
D/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): App is not loaded in QSEE
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): Error::Cannot open the file /firmware/image//sec_storage.mdt
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): Error::Loading image failed with ret = -1
E/SecureStorage( 3241): [ERROR]:Loading app sec_stor and sec_storage failed
E/SecureStorage( 3241): [ERROR]:Fail to open session with qualcomm
E/SecureStorage( 3241): [ERROR]:Error cannot connect to TA/driver!
V/AlarmManager(  348): waitForAlarm result :8
D/KeyguardClockWidgetService( 3885): onReceive action=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
V/AlarmManager(  348): ClockReceiver onReceive() ACTION_TIME_TICK
D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger(  893): checkOverflow(384), More:false, Req:false Child:4
E/SMD     (  166): DCD OFF
```

Comment: Maybe worth specifying your SDK, API and NDK information in your buildozer file. Also, I'd just check it with the [Kivy Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kivy.pygame&hl=en) to make sure it isn't the app source code itself (this way you wont need to compile it to run it for tests) .

Comment: Im confused as to what you mean? Should I uncomment the android sdk, api, and ndk lines in my buildozer file. And what do you mean I should check with the kivy launcher to make sure it isnt the app source code? Am I still using this kivy launcher when Im using buildozer?

Comment: @JoshuaDoucette: Build your Kivy App under Python 2.x and Kivy 1.10.0, and test whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be an extra backslash in filename "//sec_stor.mdt"?

```
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): Error::Cannot open the file /firmware/image//sec_stor.mdt
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): Error::Loading image failed with ret = -1
D/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): QSEECom_start_app sb_length = 0x19a040
D/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): App is not loaded in QSEE
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): Error::Cannot open the file /firmware/image//sec_storage.mdt
E/QSEECOMAPI: ( 3241): Error::Loading image failed with ret = -1
```